Apache HTTP server under DDoS attack
One of the servers has been under attack for four weeks. First the attack was weak, but now it is aggressive after I started fighting him.
It consumes CPU resources to keep starting the Apache server with the httpd -k start command.
Using the firewall, it was possible to ban it for a while, but now more than 50 unique IPs and their RANGE are under ban. Attacks frequently come from new IP addresses. Among them are many unique and well-known IP addresses of companies such as Microsoft, Amazon and others...
How to ban all "nobody" users who initiate the httpd -k start command with the help of Fail2ban, ModSecurity, or perhaps the firewall?

your question is strange, I would install fail2ban and let handle it. moreover it might help to adjust or copy the iptables rule and add on the ban action a /20

The server is under constant attack and file2bin does a very good job. But unfortunately, the attacker refined his attack and 5-7 targeted attacks out of 60 are successful. Constantly change IP addresses. I know what he is attacking. Trying start the Apache all the time till no resources left. I would like to know how I can specialize for this the file2ban?

This question is similar to: I am under DDoS. What can I do?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"It consumes CPU resources to keep starting the Apache server with the "httpd -k start" command." - This statement seems very peculiar. Please provide the relevant log entries.


How is it possible to ban all "nobody" users who initiate the "httpd -k start" command

Uhhh.
What you see is perfectly normal. And most likely not a DDOS attack.
You have enabled a web server, Apache httpd and your web site gets vistors. Some of those will be real, although often on new and (very) small web sites, the majority of your your site vistors will be automated probes and similar automated abuse attempts, the normal internet background noise and mostly harmless unless you don't regularly patch and update. Such visits are normal and expected and rarely the level that they are considered a DDoS attack or even mild abuse.
With common default settings Apache httpd more or less launches a new process for each web request and each new visitor (the pre_fork mpm is usually selected by default). Those processes automatically die off again after they've served their puprose.
Those Apache server processes must run under a system user and again nobody is common although other distributions may use httpd or something else.
The literal answer to your question "How is it possible to ban all "nobody" users who initiate the "httpd -k start" command?" is to block all web traffic in your firewall or simply disable your web server completely.

Unfortunately, the DDOS attack is still mine. Most of the attack be blocked, but the rest requires a lot of resources. I copied the entire content of the server (cloned it) to another server so the websites work without interruption. At the moment the attacker is in a separate playground and I am trying to neutralize him here. Only the Apache are under attack can't be completely dismissed. It starts a few processes and it won't stop. If I Kill it then immediately starts another one. Shutting down Apache will of course eliminate this payload attack. But that's not a solution is it?

@MarcellNemeth You show that you don't understand what you're doing or how your process works. There's no indication in what you write that you're under DDoS. Hire a competent sys admin. Your current approach is equating users with malicious users.
